# Create IoT Policy with AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-iot

I am trying to create an IoT Policy within AWS Lambda. My current Lambda Function looks like that:

```html
"use strict";
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({ region: "eu-central-1" });
var iot = new AWS.Iot();

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {


  var params = {
    policyDocument: `{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Connect"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iot:xxxxx:client/sander"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Subscribe"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iot:xxxx:topicfilter/$aws/things/ManuelBohrmaschine/shadow/*",
        "arn:aws:iot:xxxx:topicfilter/$aws/things/HeikoBohrmaschine/shadow/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Publish",
        "iot:Receive"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iot:xxxx:topic/$aws/things/ManuelBohrmaschine/shadow/*",
        "arn:aws:iot:xxxx:topic/$aws/things/HeikoBohrmaschine/shadow/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}`,
    policyName: 'sander1231564654654654',
  };
  
  
  try{

    iot.createPolicy(params, function (err, data) {
      if (err) console.log(err, err); // an error occurred
      else {
        console.log("test")
        console.log(data);
        return {
          headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", // Required for CORS support to work
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true // Required for cookies, authorization headers with HTTPS 
          },
          statusCode: 200,
          body: JSON.stringify(data)
        };

      }         
    });
  }
  catch(e){
    console.log(e);
  }
};
```

The lambda function just returns null and does not even get into the callback function of iot.createPolicy(). I also tried it without try and catch. Same problem. There is no proper error. I am using this documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Iot.html#createPolicy-property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason is that your function returns before it gets a chance to run your `iot` section. This is beacuse for [async handlers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html#nodejs-handler-async):

> If your code performs an asynchronous task, **return a promise** to make sure that it finishes running. When you resolve or reject the promise, Lambda sends the response or error to the invoker.

To overcome this, you can use `const promise = new Promise(...)` as shown in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html#nodejs-handler-async).

I modified the code to use the `Promise` pattern (see below). I can't grantee that it fully works but your function should be able to execute `iot.createPolicy` section now.

```
"use strict";
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({ region: "eu-central-1" });
var iot = new AWS.Iot();

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {

  var params = {
    policyDocument: `{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Connect"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iot:xxxxx:client/sander"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Subscribe"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iot:xxxx:topicfilter/$aws/things/ManuelBohrmaschine/shadow/*",
        "arn:aws:iot:xxxx:topicfilter/$aws/things/HeikoBohrmaschine/shadow/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Publish",
        "iot:Receive"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iot:xxxx:topic/$aws/things/ManuelBohrmaschine/shadow/*",
        "arn:aws:iot:xxxx:topic/$aws/things/HeikoBohrmaschine/shadow/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}`,
    policyName: 'sander1231564654654654',
  };

  const promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

  try{

    console.log(params);

    iot.createPolicy(params, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
          console.log(err, err); // an error occurred
          reject(Error(err));
      }
      else {
        console.log("test")
        console.log(data);
        resolve({
          headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", // Required for CORS support to work
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true // Required for cookies, authorization headers with HTTPS 
          },
          statusCode: 200,
          body: JSON.stringify(data)
        });

      }         
    });
  }
  catch(e){
    console.log(e);
  }
})
 return promise
};
```